# gt ranging column color fill

Tags: r, colors, gt

This questios arises from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68682081/2319747).

How can I range the red and green colors from gray to red and from gray to green?
I cannot apply a color ranging.

There's a partial solution

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

logistic_pattern <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  x <- args[[1]]
  thresholds <- args[[2]]
  zeros <- numeric(length(x))
  
  #sigma for normalizacion. 
  # maybe uniform sigma <- (pmax - pmin)/sqrt(12)
  sigma <- 0.2
  
  y <- 1/(1+exp(-(x - thresholds)/sigma))
  
  y
  
}
gt(df) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "gray85"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(name, performance),
      rows = between(logistic_pattern(value, threshold), 0.45, 0.55)
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(
      # color = scales::col_bin(.$threshold, domain = colfunc(10))
      color = "red"
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(name, performance),
      rows = logistic_pattern(value, threshold) < 0.45
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(
      color = "green"
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(name, performance),
      rows = logistic_pattern(value, threshold) > 0.55
    )
  )
```

I commented a failed try, but it doesn't like to R because their dimensions.

```
# colfunc <- colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "gray85", "green"))
# color = scales::col_bin(.$threshold, domain = colfunc(10))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I think what you're after is discussed [here](https://themockup.blog/static/gt-cookbook-advanced.html#Tidy_eval).

Comment: Oh, and even better. The new [gtExtras package](https://jthomasmock.github.io/gtExtras/) does what you're asking about and a lot more.

Comment: A was looking around this, but their functions ever points to the data inside the same column, no another.